# How can I dynamically load the title of a Scrolling Activity based on user input?

Tags: java, android

I'm making an app where, so far, the user selects a place through the Google Places API, then a new scrolling activity appears and gives details about the place.  How can I change the title of the scrolling activity based on the name of the place the user chooses?

Comment: please add xml file and if possible link to screenhot (we want to see your so far great job :-D )

Comment: I don't understand. Can't u just use setText?  Or am I missing something? Thank you

Answer (score 10):

```
CollapsingToolbarLayout toolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);
toolbarLayout.setTitle("New Title.");
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("New Title");
```

Answer (score 1):

To change the title of an activity, use setTitle inside the activity.
Ex.
    setTitle("myActivity);

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do set up toolbar_layout properties from your activity then enable Title and set the title for the toolbar:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail)

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    toolbar_layout.isTitleEnabled = true
    toolbar_layout.title = "My new Title"
}
```

Comment: Thats simple all you need to do set up toolbar_layout properties from your activity then enable Title and set the title for the toolbar ...